# PHP echo loop is breaking CSS flex box

Tags: php, css, flexbox, echo

It looks like a PHP echo loop is cancelling out css flex box.
The code still dynamically displays and the font, etc.. correspond correctly to the css however on the page the "a" tags don't wrap to a new line. They extend off the page.

When I removes the dynamically  generated "a" tags and hard code them they wrap.

How do you recommend I loop php content into html and have it work with css flex box?

> CSS

```
.flex-center {
align-items: center;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}
```

> HTML / PHP

```
    <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="links">
                <?php
                foreach ($channels as $channel) {
                    $count ++;
                    echo   "<a>dasdsadsad</a>";
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: `echo "<a>dasdsadsad</a>\n";`

Comment: @u_mulder Thanks. Works. Why does this not newline at every <a>

Comment: Because `php` just echoes text. It won't echo newline if you don't code it.

Comment: With CSS: `.flex-center .links a {
  display: block; 
 }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP doesn't care about new lines. It will not echo newlines unless you explicitly tell to echo them. It can be done for example with such code:

```
foreach ($channels as $channel) {
    $count ++;
    echo   "<a>dasdsadsad</a>\n";  // note `\n` in the end of string
}
```

More cross-platform solution is to use `PHP_EOL` (End Of Line) constant, which contains either `"\r\n"` or `"\n"` depending on server's operation system:

```
foreach ($channels as $channel) {
    $count ++;
    echo   "<a>dasdsadsad</a>" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Also something like this may work too (but needs to be checked):

```
foreach ($channels as $channel) {
    $count ++;?>
    <a>dasdsadsad</a>
<?php
}
```

Also included @devpro solution with css:

```
.flex-center .links a { display: block; }
```

Comment: @devpro I included your option with css too.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the break

```
echo "<a>dasdsadsad</a><br />";
```

I hope this is all you want.